# By using "onmouseover" is it possible to stack a transparent png on a map?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transparency, onmouseover

Sorry to bother with something which may be so stupid to accomplish but I'm stuck.
I've tried in many ways to get the "onmouseover" to stack a transparent picture on top of the map image,but I couldn't get it right.
I've renounced to the possibility of using PNG images and I've used JPG pictures to make my map but the result is poor because I'm making a map of a country which is huge and having compressed 8 bit PNGs can save a lot of space in this case,compared to compressed JPGs, which are ugly and have a bigger size(in this case at least).
By the way, here's the code of an example map with a Javascript to resize it.
Please,notice that the JS doesn't work in the fiddle but it does with my original map.I had to leave it to make things clear since i really need it and any possible solution should take it into consideration.

Here's the code:

```
<area id="planA" alt="" title="planA" href="#" shape="rect" coords="184,122,408,322" style="outline:none;" target="_self"  onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('choices-map-img').src= 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/5/8/e/1298546227709322759png-transparency.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('choices-map-img').src= 'http://blogs-images.forbes.com/jacobmorgan/files/2015/03/Choice.jpg';"  />

<area id="planB" alt="" title="planB" href="#" shape="rect" coords="572,125,796,318" style="outline:none;" target="_self"  onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('choices-map-img').src= 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/5/8/e/1298546227709322759png-transparency.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('choices-map-img').src= 'http://blogs-images.forbes.com/jacobmorgan/files/2015/03/Choice.jpg';"  />
</map>
```

[Here's the fiddle with JS.](https://jsfiddle.net/nwnycoyg/2/)

In sum, what I would like to see is the dices over the background image with transparency working.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Just as @TomMon-Tom posted use png to obtain transparency. Also JPG's do not have alpha channel , so there is no chance you are going to get away with that.

Comment: maybe the description is misleading, but I know I should use PNG images, the problem is that the onmouseover is switching the image completely while,as I asked,I need it to be transparent on top of the background. :/
Do you know what should I do to make it ?

Comment: Try the fiddle, it uses a PNG on top of a JPEG but the picture gets exchanged with that method.
If you know how to stack it on top of the previous,I'll be glad to hear it.
That's all about this.

Comment: @friends.call.memcyborg Ok, Now got what you asking for. So i think i know how it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

PNGs are the way to go since they can contain data for an alpha channel unlike any other image format. Why do they need to be JPGs? You say yourself 8 bit PNGs save space which they do in certain instances. I'd change them to PNGs if this was me.

Comment: **This doesn't answer the question.** Maybe the description is misleading, but I know I should use PNG images, the problem is that the onmouseover is switching the image completely while,as I asked,I need it to be transparent on top of the background. :/ Do you know what should I do to make it work ? Or else, please, read carefully before answering...

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by stacking images one over other. Also i need JQuery Library to use mouseover &  mouseout.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yyh413fg/)

```js
$( "#planA" ).mouseover(function() {
    $("#plan_a").css("display","block");
    $("#plan_a").css("width","1000");    
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
     $("#plan_a").css("display","none");
  });

$( "#planB" ).mouseover(function() {
    $("#plan_b").css("display","block");
    $("#plan_b").css("width","1000");    
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
     $("#plan_b").css("display","none");
  });
```

```css
.main
{
 display:block;
 width:100%;
}

.main img
{
 float:left;
 left:0px;
 position:absolute;
 width:1000;
}

#plan_a, #plan_b
{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
 <img id="main_img" src="http://blogs-images.forbes.com/jacobmorgan/files/2015/03/Choice.jpg" usemap="#choices" alt=""/>
 <map name="choices" id="choices-id">
  <area id="planA" alt="" title="planA" href="#" shape="rect" coords="184,122,408,322" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
  <area id="planB" alt="" title="planB" href="#" shape="rect" coords="572,125,796,318" style="outline:none;" target="_self" /> 
  </map> 
 <img id="plan_a" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/5/8/e/1298546227709322759png-transparency.png" usemap="#choices" />
 <img id="plan_b" src="http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggradHDrgba.png" usemap="#choices" />
</div>
```

> Note: Stacking of images can be done multiple ways , mine is this. Go
>   with whatever you prefer suitable for you.

Comment: **this doesn't take into account the JS in the fiddle**
(you removed it)
It works , ok , but without the resizer , it's half resolved. :/
It's written **"any possible solution should take it into consideration."**
:P

Comment: By the way, it's fine, I can try to fix that on my own ^_^"
Thanx a lot for your effort, I really appreciated it :)

Comment: I solved the resizer problem by adding 100% both in the css and in your javascript.
It's perfect now, I don't know how to thank you, you're awesome. :D
You should put a donation button somewhere in your profile. ;)

Comment: Glad, that you found it useful.